Finding prior when there is a previous prior
This is a practice question from Marshall Wace:

[14 marks] In a legal dispute over paternity, Adam is the alleged father.

The judge is a Bayesian statistician, and announces at the start that, in the interests of fairness, his prior belief is that there is a $50\%$ chance Adam is the father.

On the first day of the trial, testimonials are given.

On the second day, it is revealed that the child has blood type $B$, and according to geneticists, this would happen with probability $50\%$ if Adam is the father. Furthermore, based on incidence rates of $B$ genes in the population, there is a $10\%$ chance that this child would have blood type $B$ if Adam is not the father.

At the end of the second day, the judge announces that his assessment of the probability that Adam is the father is $75\%$.

$\text{(a)}$ [5 marks] What were the judge's beliefs at the end of the first day?

My approach
Let

$P(A \mid B)$ = probability that Adam is the father given blood type $B$. This is $0.75$
$P(B \mid A)$ = probability that if Adam is the father, the child has blood type $B$ - this is $0.5$
$P(B \mid A')$ = probability that if Adam is not the father, the child has blood type $B$

We need to find $P(A)$ - the probability that Adam is the father (i.e. the prior). Solving this, we have
$$
P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A) \, P(B \mid A)}{P(A) \, P(B \mid A) + P(A') \, P(B \mid A')}
$$
$$
0.75 = \frac{0.5x}{0.5x + 0.1(1 - x)}
$$
$$
x = \frac{3}{8}
$$
I find this answer confusing, especially because it makes no use of his announcement that his prior belief (before the trial) is $0.5$, which means that he was sceptical after the first day before correcting his beliefs at the end of the second day. I think I am missing something, and I would appreciate assistance.

As is often the case with such questions, the phrasing leaves a lot to be desired.  For example, if the judge's prior belief already took the blood type into account, then learning that blood type would not change the estimate.  More subtly, problems arise if the judge's prior is somehow correlated to the blood type.  Clearly you are intended to neglect all these concerns, but they are not incidental.

Well, this question is marked part (a). Does the original prior bear on some of the other parts perhaps?

As to your question, yes it does look like the $.5$ prior is irrelevant here.  The testimony produced a new prior and it is that new prior you are trying to compute.  Of course, all my concerns about the prior apply to the new one as well.

All of that said, I agree that $\frac 38$ is the answer to the intended question.

@BrianTung I don't think that's the case (being an interview-style problem) - I left the other two parts since I intend to ask them separately if I get stuck in them. The source for reference is https://cdn.mwam.com/download/MW_Quant_Application_Guide.pdf

FWIW, I also get $3/8$ for the answer to the question as stated here.
